# vb.net encoding.unicode.getbytes issue

Tags: vb.net, csv, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to export data from an SQL Server database to a csv file in a zipped folder using vb.net (framework version 3.5) for transmission to other users. All works fine except when the data in a field contains the euro symbol or when it's been pasted into a text field from a web page - then the output csv seems to contain null characters that throw off the csv parsers (including Excel's) resulting in line breaks that shouldn't be there (I've enclosed any fields with multiple lines in double quotes).

I've traced it down to certain characters in the text that seem to upset Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes - it replaces them with a null character. If I use Encoding.Default.GetBytes that works OK, but then I run the risk of the sender and receiver using different code pages and the possibility that the receiver won't be able to import the data.

As I mentioned, one of the problem characters is the euro symbol (chr(128)), others include chr(130 to 140) and chr(145 to 156).

So what I have at the moment is:

```
 Dim b() As Byte = Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(itm.ItemText)

 pkgpart.GetStream().Write(b, 0, b.Length)
```

which works, but the preferred:

```
 Dim b() As Byte = Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(itm.ItemText)

 pkgpart.GetStream().Write(b, 0, b.Length)
```

doesn't.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing in order to get the Unicode.Getbytes method to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any program that can accept a CSV file will never assume it was encoded in Encoding.Unicode.  It *might* be able to handle a Unicode encoding (Encoding.UTF8 first) if the file has a BOM.  Get ahead by using StreamWriter instead so you have better control over the BOM.  Trying to instantly create a .zip file got you into this trouble.

Comment: But wouldn't the same thing happen if I tried to convert any field with those characters into a byte array, regardless of what I'm using the byte array for? Maybe the question should be is there a way to convert a string containing the characters in question to a byte array?

Comment: The problem is that Unicode is a 2-byte encoding, and unless the receiver is expecting that, it will assume that the 2nd byte of each character (which will be 0) is a NULL character.  UTF8 gets around that by having different byte lengths for various character codes.  If you use StreamWriter, you can have it issue the Unicode BOM (Byte Order Mark) which will tell most things that it's UTF8.

Comment: @user8843348 Please move your update out of the question and to an answer. Accept it once you think it is the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Hans and dwilliss for putting me on the right track. Adding the BOM and using UTF-8 as per below got it working fine.

```
Dim b() As Byte = Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble.Concat(Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(itm.ItemText)).ToArray
pkgpart.GetStream().Write(b, 0, b.Length)
```

Thanks again